# How do you exclude a column from showing up if there is no value?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Question about a query I'm trying to write in SQL Server  Management Studio 2008.  I am pulling 2 rows.  The first row being the header information, the second row being the information for a certain Line Item.  Keep in mind, the actual header information reads as "Column 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,.... etc."

The data looks something like this:

```
ROW 1: Model # | Item Description| XS |  S  |  M  | L  | XL|
ROW 2:  3241   |  Gray Sweatshirt|    |  20 | 20  | 30 |   |
```

Basically this shows that there are 20 smalls, 20 mediums, and 30 larges of this particular item.  There are no XS's or XL's.

I want to create a subquery that puts this information in one row, but at the same time, disinclude the sizes with a blank quantity amount as shown under the XS and XL sizes.

I want it to look like this when all is said and done:

```
ROW 1: MODEL #| 3241 | ITEM DESCRIPTION | Gray Sweatshirt | S | 10 | M | 20 | L | 30 |
```

Notice there are no XS or XL's included.  How do I do make it so those columns do not appear?

Comment: Please post the query you are using that includes the nulls

Comment: It looks like you're doing too much *presentation logic* in your queries to pull the data.  A better solution would be to have the database only responsible for returning the raw, unformatted data... and leave the formatting to the application showing the data.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Is absolutely right - just pull the data in SQL and let your application/presentation layer worry about how to display it.  SQL is not great at this kind of thing and the performance and ease of use will be a lot better if it's handled in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not posting your query, nor your table structure, I guess it is with columns Id, Description, Size. If so, you could do this and just replace with your table and column names:

```
DECLARE @columns varchar(8000)    
SELECT @columns = COALESCE (@columns + ',[' + cast(Size as varchar) + ']', '[' + cast(Size as varchar) + ']' )
            FROM   YourTableName
            WHERE     COUNT(Size) > 0

            DECLARE @query varchar(8000) = 'SELECT Id, Description, '
                + @columns +'
                FROM
                (SELECT Id, Description, Size
                 FROM YourTableName) AS Source
                PIVOT
                (
                    COUNT(Size)
                    FOR Size IN ('+ @columns +')
                ) AS Pvt'

            EXEC(@query)
```

Anyhow, I also agree with @MichaelFredickson. I have implemented this pivot solution, yet it is absolutely better to let the presentation layer to take care of this after just pulling the raw data from SQL. If not, you would be processing the data twice, one on SQL to create the table and the other in the presentation when reading and displaying the values with your c#/vb/other code.

Comment: And if you are developing using ASP.Net WebForms, then you can create a sp and pass it as a datasource to a gridview which will dynamically read your columns with no further coding. Not the most efficient way though!